# telegram-send doesn't work after reinstall miniconda3

Tags: python-telegram-bot

This is my code. it works fine when I start it and send /help to telegram.
'bot is initialized' means it's fine I think..
but.. why.. why... no '33333'...
I tested it like this again and again and again...

1. make new virtual env
2. pip install aiogram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-send..
   (my env is 39 )
   help.. ㅠㅠ

import asyncio
import logging
import time
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import subprocess
import threading

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='bot_log.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

class Object:

```
test = 'Off' # 'On/Off'

### token, id ########
TOKEN_1 = '#######'
CHAT_ID_1 = #######
```

class AI_Dealer_Boo:

```
def __init__(self, token: str, chat_id: int):
    self.token = token
    self.chat_id = chat_id

    self.bot = Bot(token=self.token)

    self.dp = Dispatcher(self.bot)

    self.dp.register_message_handler(self.echo_message, commands=None)

def send_telegram_message(self, message):
    try:
        subprocess.run(['telegram-send', message], check=True)
        print('Telegram message sent successfully')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print('Telegram message sending failed:', e)

def on_event(self):
    message = '11111.'
    self.send_telegram_message(message)

async def echo_message(self, message: types.Message):
    if message.text == '/run':
        result = 100 * 12345
        await message.answer(f'a * 12345 = {result}')

    elif message.text == '/help':
        await message.answer("\n===== 22222 ========"
              "\n%s"
              "\n%s"
              "\n%s"
              "\n======================"
              % (message.text, message.text, message.text))

    else:
        await message.answer("unknown.")


async def start(self):

    await self.bot.send_message(self.chat_id, 'bot is initialized.')

    await self.dp.start_polling()
```

class BotThread(threading.Thread):
def **init**(self, bot):
super().**init**()
self.bot = bot

```
def run(self):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(self.bot.start())
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
logging.info("Bot starting...")

TOKEN = '########'
CHAT_ID = ########

dealer = AI_Dealer_Boo(TOKEN, CHAT_ID)

asyncio.run(dealer.start())

ai_Dealer = AI_Dealer_Boo(token=Object.TOKEN_1, chat_id=Object.CHAT_ID_1)
ai_Dealer.send_telegram_message("33333")
```

I've made a new env and pip install what is needed like all day long..